# VB WebClient returns 403 and an XML document, but I can't access the document

Tags: xml, vb.net, webclient

What's going on here is that I'm taking API key data from a list of database entries and concatenating them onto a string that will be used as a URL. That URL is then used to access an API endpoint through a WebClient object which returns an XML document. In the past, this method has worked well enough, but in the instance where I'm using an API key to access an endpoint without the proper permissions, the server returns with an XML document stating such and an HTTP 403 error code. For whatever reason, the document is locked behind the error code and isn't available through the usual means of e.Result. Attempting to access e.Result throws a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

Is there another way to retrieve the XML document? Here's a cutdown of the code if that helps:

```
    Public Sub DetermineValidKeys()
    Dim AccountStatusURL As String = "https://api.eveonline.com/Account/AccountStatus.xml.aspx"
    Try
        Dim KeyID As String = Entries.Item(1).KeyID
        Dim VCode As String = Entries.Item(1).VerificationCode
        Dim URL As New Uri(AccountStatusURL + "?keyID=" + KeyID + "&vCode=" + VCode)
        Dim web As New WebClient()
        web.Proxy = Nothing
        AddHandler web.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf EntryValidationCheck
        web.DownloadStringAsync(URL)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub EntryValidationCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    Try
        RichTextBox1.Text = e.Result
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: HTTP 403 is "Forbidden" - that means whatever resource you were trying to access at that URI is not allowing you access.   I doubt there is anything in `e.Result`, based on the error you received.  Was there a sub code returned (i.e., 403.1, 403.2, etc)?

Comment: It is an assumption that a document was returned when the WebClient object made the request. The reason I say that a document was returned is because I can enter in the same address into a web browser and it will display an XML document. While in developer mode in Firefox, I can see that a 403 is returned.